# Filter DACPAC file based on input object list

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, azure-synapse

Currently I have a Azure DevOps release pipeline for Azure Synapse DW incremental deployment using DACPAC file and it's working fine. Now, I want a filter to be implemented on DACPAC file in order to include only specific objects after comparison and only those objects will be deployed to target database. As we generally have many tables/stored procedure crated in dev environment and those cannot be deployed onto higher environments.
I tried DacFX API to exclude all `Delete`, `Add` and `Changed` operations using below code snippet and then include only objects that need to be deployed. But it's taking very long time to exclude objects.
Note: Here I'm dealing with around 3k objects.

```
$comparisonResult.Differences | %{
        if($_.UpdateAction -eq "Delete") {
            $comparisonResult.Exclude($_) | Out-Null
    }
}

$comparisonResult.Differences | %{
        if($_.UpdateAction -eq "Change") {
            $comparisonResult.Exclude($_) | Out-Null
    }
}

$comparisonResult.Differences | %{
        if($_.UpdateAction -eq "Add") {
            $comparisonResult.Exclude($_) | Out-Null
    }
}

#start including required objects
$objectList = @('schema1.table1'
,'schema1.table2'
,'schema2.view_sample1'
,'schema2.table4')

Write-Host "Including objects from the provided list... "
$comparisonResult.Differences | %{
        if($_.SourceObject.Count -gt 0)
        {
            $schemaName=$_.SourceObject.Name.parts[0]
            $objectName = $_.SourceObject.Name.parts[1]
            $finalObjectToInclude = $schemaName + "." + $objectName
            if( $objectList -contains $finalObjectToInclude)
            {
                Write-Output "Including Object $($finalObjectToInclude)"
                $comparisonResult.Include($_) | Out-Null
            }
        }
}
```

Need your expert advise to make it work or any other suggestion is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.